# separating values of CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES variable

Tags: bash, cuda, hpc, slurm

I am running a job in a cluster that uses SLURM as a scheduler. I specify the type of GPU card with the option `--gres=gpu:k80`. However, because the cluster has nodes with a different number of cards, it happens that sometimes one gets 2 or 4. I can see the available devices with:

```sh
echo $CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES
```

which reports a list, 0,1 or 0,1,2,3. I need the maximum value of the list either 1 or 3. Here is my question: is there some option in SLURM to know that?

Comment: So would getting the highest number from the array be enough?

Comment: I am using the following hack: ```export num_dev=`echo $CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES | awk 'BEGIN{FS=","};{print NF}'` ``` which works but seems a bit obscure

Comment: I think you should aim for the length of that list.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify with

```
export num_def=${CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: -1}
```

Slurm can provide you with the information, though it will be more difficult to parse. For instance,

```
squeue -J $SLURM_JIBID -O tres-alloc:100
```

will show something like

```
cpu=1,mem=1000M,node=1,billing=1,gres/gpu=1
```

and the last number here is the number of GPUs allocated to the job.